# using the setOnItemSelectedListener and onNothingSelected with spinner

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, spinner, android-spinner

I was just wondering if anyone can help me resolve the problem which i am currently facing as I am trying to implement setOnItemSelectedListener and onNothingSelected events with spinner.

Once the user selects option from spinner it will show them google places names, then when the user clicks on a place ,it will show another page which is called details.java and this contains details of the place as well as mapview.

I think I am using both of the particular options incorrectly, therefore please can someone help and advise me?.

```
public class PlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public ArrayList<GetterSetter> myArrayList;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Spinner spinner;
    ListView myList;
    private String[] places;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    TextView nodata;
    PlaceAdapter adapter;
    GetterSetter addValues;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);

        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable internet connection and RE-LAUNCH!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        places = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setTitle("Title");

        spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerplaces);


        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> listAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.places,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        listAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(PlaceActivity.this, R.array.places,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        list.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait", true);
        // Google Places Access key and location values.
        new readFromGooglePlaceAPI()
                .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
                        + "location=53.795984,-1.759398&radius=900&sensor=true&"
                        + "key=AIzaSyA7CzOa10AOfBAU9FvaIrVlVyCKzXxiCc0&types="
                        + places[itemPosition]);
        myList.OnItemSelectedListener(this);
        return true;


    }

    public class readFromGooglePlaceAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
            return readJSON(param[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
            myArrayList = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();
            try {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(str);
                JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject arrayItems = results.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject geometry = arrayItems.getJSONObject("geometry");
                    JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
                    addValues = new GetterSetter();
                    addValues.setLat(location.getString("lat"));
                    addValues.setLon(location.getString("lng"));
                    addValues.setName(arrayItems.getString("name").toString());
                    addValues.setRating(arrayItems.getString("rating").toString());
                    addValues.setVicinity(arrayItems.getString("vicinity").toString());
                    myArrayList.add(addValues);

                    Log.d("Before", myArrayList.toString());

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            System.out
                    .println("############################################################################");
            Log.d("After:", myArrayList.toString());
            nodata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nodata);
            nodata.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter = new PlaceAdapter(PlaceActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, myArrayList);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public String readJSON(String URL) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON", "Couldn't find JSON file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // no-op
    }
```

where do I put the below code.

```
 @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent details = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
        details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
        details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
        details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
        details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
        details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
        startActivity(details);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're in the right direction. Right now you have the necessary methods, but you have make your class implement the OnItemSelectedListener and set it as the listener for your spinner as such:

public class PlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 **implements OnItemSelectedListener** {
    ...
}

And then to set the class as the listener you can add this line after: spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerplaces);

**spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);**

Comment: Could you elaborate on what happened when you made the changes?

Comment: i could see the snipper, however nothing happened once clicked on the list options. please help.

Comment: where do I put the below code.   @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent details = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
        details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
        details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
        details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
        details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
        details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
        startActivity(details);
    }

Comment: just to clarify, the Google places data you get after the user selects an option from the spinner is used to populate your listview correct? if that is so then all you need to do us set the listener for the ListView. I can't give you show you the code right now but the Android Guide for ListView should have an example on how to do that. Also, I'm that listener you will have the on click method where that code above goes.

Comment: Yes this is correct. its just that I used Sherlock Actionbar which is no longer available in new Android SDK. I left Andriod for IOS and when I came back they have changed so many things. I am clueless now.

Comment: Haha yeah they changed a few things around. Check out this link, at the bottom there is a section named Handling  click events which shows you how to add the listener for the list. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I cant see the link, can you post it again please.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                               int pos, long id) {
//If you're wondering, int pos is the position of the item selected (starting with 0)
// what you want onClick
}
```

Your code:

```
 @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent details = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
        details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
        details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
        details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
        details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
        details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
        startActivity(details);
    }
```

can go below the initialization of the spinner.

Hope it helps! Good Luck!